# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v4:23.0.0

Tags: android, api, gradle

estoy usando Android Studio versión 3, el celular con que pruebo usa el api 23, por eso intenté cambiar el gradle, pero me sale el mensaje de error
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v4:23.0.0

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.jhon.edittextvalidation2"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v4:23.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Prueba a añadir esto allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

Comment: A ver si añadiendo el repositorio de maven te lo coge

Comment: te recomiendo que uses siempre la última version de todo, del gradle, de la api, de las librerías que uses. Da igual si tu móvil es API 23, la última API ya va adaptada para que funcione en tu móvil con API 23.

Comment: En qué parte? Aquí no se pueden subir imágenes?

Comment: Lo tienes que poner en el archivo build.gradle pero no en el que has puesto(ese es el que está a nivel de proyecto), lo tienes que poner en el fichero build.gradle a nivel de aplicación. Al mismo nivel que dependencies. Si que se pueden subir imágenes, cuando editas la pregunta sale una I para subir una imagen

Comment: Use la api 27, estoy ejecutando en mi celular y me sale este error: Session 'app': Error Installing APK

Comment: La minima si que tiene que ser al menos la de tu movil, pero la compilacion y la target la última. 
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28

Comment: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02] C:\Users\JHON\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0-rc02.aar\df2090dc717a0307c1d780ad6cf51f46\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 7
 Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 7,
  or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 14,
  or use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)